# Extra new line at the end of json variable

Tags: android, json, kotlin, http, networking

I have a string

> 3e8c837f-907e-46dd-9f71-697ccbb065d6

which I encode to base64.
After encoding via `Base64.encodeToString(this.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), Base64.DEFAULT)` the output is equal to:

> M2U4YzgzN2YtOTA3ZS00NmRkLTlmNzEtNjk3Y2NiYjA2NWQ2

Everything is fine but when I put this String to JSONObject() like that:

```
val json = JSONObject()
json.put("id", encodedId)
```

The id value in sended json looks like:

```
"id":"M2U4YzgzN2YtOTA3ZS00NmRkLTlmNzEtNjk3Y2NiYjA2NWQ2\n"
```

As you can see there is extra

> \n

. What can be wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `\n` there is a characteristic of the `Base64.DEFAULT` in android. If you want to remove it, you can replace it with `Base64.NO_WRAP`.

```kotlin
Base64.encodeToString(this.toByteArray(Charsets.UTF_8), Base64.NO_WRAP)
```